# How do I link SharePoint data to a shape using Visio Services?

Tags: visio-services

I am trying out Visio Services in SharePoint 2010.

I started to link data to shapes.  I selected Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Services list in the Data Selector dialog box, imported a visio diagram, added the url to the site.

I then selected  Link to a list -> Tasks.

When I try to 'Automatically Link Data Column to Shape Field' I can not see Shape Field ID.
How can I add Shape Field ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting, can you still generate a data driven visio diagram from SharePoint using the method described in [this](http://www.whatsthepointofsharing.com/2010/03/01/task-list-export-access-project-and-visio/%20under%20the%20'Create%20Visio%20Diagram'%20section?) article.